# Have the screensaver enable or disable depending on power profile?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I would like to be able to enable and disable the screensaver when I switch power profiles. Say I had 2 profiles, balanced and high performance, I want to have the screensaver show while on balanced but if I switch to high performance the screensaver will disable leaving the screen in an always on state. I have searched around Google and came up with a few similar results, none of which were helpful.

I tried [caffeine](http://lifehacker.com/5244214/caffeine-disables-or-enables-the-screensaver-easily) it was good except for when I had ssh open it would make htop move it's cursor.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the command prompt type `powercfg -l` (that's a lower-case 'L')
2. Note the **GUIDs** for the **Balanced** and **High performance** power schemes
3. Configure your screensaver, timeout etc. as usual
4. Open Notepad, copy/paste the following and save as **"Balanced.bat"** (with the quotes):

   ```
   powercfg -s <Balanced Power Scheme GUID>
   reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveActive /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
   ```
5. Open Notepad, copy/paste the following and save as **"HighPerformance.bat"** (with the quotes):

   ```
   powercfg -s <High performance Power Scheme GUID>
   reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveActive /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f
   ```

Note: Do not include the `<>` characters when entering the **GUIDs** in the batch files.