# How can I link a keyboard shortcut to different power plans/profiles in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-management

For example, the different power plans I have available on my Dell e6420 are listed as:
[image]

How can I link these options w/ a keyboard shortcut, such that I could either a) toggle through them, or b) iterate through the plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/546045/138343), you can check the **GUIDs** for the various plans and create separate shortcuts (with keyboard shortcuts) to `Windows\System32\Powercfg.exe` to activate each plan (pay attention to the **Target** field below):

[image: 1]

However, in order to make things easier so you don't have to look up and carefully copy+paste all those GUIDs, I cooked up a couple of batch files for you.

The first one, **PowerPlanAlter.bat**, will enable you to quickly switch between all available plans on your system using just a number. Running it without an argument will print something like this:

```
Usage: PowerPlanAlter [Number]

  1 = "Balanced" [GUID = 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e]
  2 = "High performance" [GUID = 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c]
  3 = "My Custom Plan 1 (Reduced fan speeds)" [GUID = 938ef152-e95f-4aed-acea-e1c8a0f4493f]
  4 = "My Custom Plan 1 (Increased fan speeds)" [GUID = 9d2a75cb-f035-4376-92db-36fa01e271d2]
  5 = "Power saver" [GUID = a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a]

Current power plan = "Balanced" [GUID = 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e]
```

You can call it from the command line or create multiple shortcuts to it, one per plan. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
set pcnt=0
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=3 tokens=2* delims=:(" %%a in ('powercfg -l') do (
    set /a pcnt+=1
    set tmp=%%b
    if [!tmp:~-1!]==[^)] set tmp=!tmp:~,-1!
    if [!tmp:~-1!]==[*] set tmp=!tmp:~,-3!&& set cp=!pcnt!
    set pname_!pcnt!=!tmp!
    for /f %%c in ("%%a") do set pguid_!pcnt!=%%c
)
echo.
powercfg -s !pguid_%1! 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Usage: %0 [Number]
    echo.
    for /l %%d in (1,1,!pcnt!) do echo   %%d = "!pname_%%d!" [GUID = !pguid_%%d!]
    echo.
    for /l %%e in (!cp!,1,!cp!) do echo Current power plan = "!pname_%%e!" [GUID = !pguid_%%e!]
) else (
    for /l %%f in (!cp!,1,!cp!) do echo Old power plan = "!pname_%%f!" [GUID = !pguid_%%f!]
    echo.
    echo New power plan = "!pname_%1!" [GUID = !pguid_%1!]
)
```

The second one, **PowerPlanCycle.bat**, will enable you to quickly cycle/iterate through all available plans on your system. No arguments required; just create a shortcut to it and every time you run it the next plan in line will be activated (cycling back to the first one after the last). Here's the code:

```
@echo off
set pcnt=0
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=3 tokens=2* delims=:(" %%a in ('powercfg -l') do (
    set /a pcnt+=1
    set tmp=%%b
    if [!tmp:~-1!]==[^)] set tmp=!tmp:~,-1!
    if [!tmp:~-1!]==[*] set tmp=!tmp:~,-3!&& set cp=!pcnt!
    set pname_!pcnt!=!tmp!
    for /f %%c in ("%%a") do set pguid_!pcnt!=%%c
)
echo.
set /a np=!cp!%%!pcnt!+1
for /l %%d in (!cp!,1,!cp!) do echo Old power plan = "!pname_%%d!" [GUID = !pguid_%%d!]
echo.
for /l %%e in (!np!,1,!np!) do powercfg -s !pguid_%%e! && echo New power plan = "!pname_%%e!" [GUID = !pguid_%%e!]
```

If you're calling these via a shortcut and want to see the output, just add a `pause` command at the end. These work fine on Windows 7 x64, but let me know if you have a problem with them.

(Oh, and just in case you're not too familiar with batch files, just copy+paste the code into Notepad and save as "PowerPlanAlter.bat" and "PowerPlanCycle.bat" respectively, *with* the quotes.)

Comment: Also, there's relevant information on this MS KB @ http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935799